# Sockets: BufferedReader readLine()

Tags: java, sockets

I am using BufferedReader.readLine() method to read a response from a remote server

```
   String com;
   while ((com = bufferedReader.readLine()) == null) 
    {
    System.out.println(com+"\n");
    }
```

i was using following code and i got output like this

```
GET http://bioactress.blogspot.in/ HTTP/1.1

Host: bioactress.blogspot.in

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/
14.0.1

 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

  Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5

 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

  If-Modified-Since: Sat, 17 Nov 2012 07:43:35 GMT

 If-None-Match: "7f9584f0-06ba-448e-97a4-2b8bcd0b30b1"

  Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

How to retrieve  the host address only .i was try with array not some error will occur.please help me any one to get the host address

Answer (score 0):

> to read a response from a remote server

Based on the output you are reading a request from a remote client, but nevermind...

> How to retrieve the host address only

Use [`String.startsWith(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if(com.startsWith("Host:"))
```

I'll leave extracting of the actual value and dealing with character case (HTTP headers are case-insensitive) to you.

BTW why won't you use some higher-level API like servlets?

Answer (score 0):

What you show is HTTP *request*, not a response. Then the code you posted is not real - it doesn't actually print anything read from the stream (condition is reversed, it should be `!=` instead).

There many resources online that show how to use Java sockets. Google is your friend there. You can start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) or use some higher-level things like [`java.net.URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).